# MixedModel with missing values in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, missing-data, mixed-models

Can't run a MixedModel when response variables has `missing`.
I get `ERROR: KeyError: key missing not found`

Previously Julia could run this without an issue.

I load my data using CSV.read, but the example below uses a dataset from an R package called `languageR`

```
using DataFrames, MixedModels, GLM, RDatasets, RData, RCall, Missings, CSV

#load data
lexdec = rcopy(R"languageR::lexdec")

#replace one value with missing
lexdec.rt = recode(lexdec.RT, 6.905753 => missing)

#run mixedmodel
fm = fit(MixedModel, @formula(rt ~ 1 + Class*NativeLanguage*Frequency + Trial + (1|Subject) + (1|Word)), lexdec)

ERROR: KeyError: key missing not found
#plus a long Stacktrace
```

Same error if an independent variable has missing (say Frequency). Would like a solution that can address missing in both cases.

Comment: You might consider opening an issue on MixedModels https://github.com/dmbates/MixedModels.jl/issues/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Development version of MixedModels can handle missing values. Looks like it just removes the row with a missing value. This is the same as `na.omit` in `R`.

```
#install development version
add https://github.com/dmbates/MixedModels.jl

julia> #run mixedmodel
       fm = fit(MixedModel, @formula(rt ~ 1 + Class*NativeLanguage*Frequency + Trial + (1|Subject) + (1|Word)), lexdec)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood
 rt ~ 1 + Class + NativeLanguage + Frequency + Trial + Class & NativeLanguage + Class & Frequency + NativeLanguage & Frequency + Class & NativeLanguage & Frequency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Word)
   logLik    -2 logLik      AIC         BIC     
   500.93350 -1001.86699  -977.86699  -912.90658

Variance components:
            Column     Variance    Std.Dev.  
Word     (Intercept)  0.0023721041 0.04870425
Subject  (Intercept)  0.0166347779 0.12897588
Residual              0.0290821397 0.17053486
 Number of obs: 1658; levels of grouping factors: 79, 21

  Fixed-effects parameters:
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                      Estimate   Std.Error     z value  P(>|z|)
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)                                        6.52805      0.0594568   109.795      <1e-99
Class: plant                                      -0.0575706    0.0630526    -0.913056   0.3612
NativeLanguage: Other                              0.378076     0.0753413     5.01817    <1e-6 
Frequency                                         -0.0371412    0.00860268   -4.3174     <1e-4 
Trial                                             -0.000233949  9.0215e-5    -2.59324    0.0095
Class: plant & NativeLanguage: Other              -0.108593     0.0685904    -1.58322    0.1134
Class: plant & Frequency                           0.00893183   0.0130981     0.68192    0.4953
NativeLanguage: Other & Frequency                 -0.0398737    0.00936592   -4.25732    <1e-4 
Class: plant & NativeLanguage: Other & Frequency   0.0078122    0.014241      0.54857    0.5833
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: That command does not install the development version, but the current release

Comment: Well, why do I get `MixedModels v2.1.2 #master (https://github.com/dmbates/MixedModels.jl)` for pkg status? That's not what release packages show install with `add [pkg name]`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, that does install the most recent release, sorry! I'm used to the more standard syntax `] add MixedModels#master`